# drupal 7. how to refactor a form array

Tags: drupal, refactoring

I am creating a wizard from the Drupal example file and would like to refactor the segments of code that are repeated when setting up items like options and radios.

I have already tried a simple function passing "ordinary" and "preferential" but can't find a way to make it work.

Can someone give me an idea of the best way to do this?

unfactored code is as below:

```
function services_wizard_share_capital_classes($form, &$form_state) {

$form['share_classes']['type_of_class'] = array(
'#type' => 'select',
'#title' => t('What type of share will this class be?'),
'#options' => array(
  1 => t('Ordinary'),
  2 => t('Preferential'),
),
);

$form['ordinary']['share_type'] = array(
'#type' => 'item',
'#description' => t("You chose Ordinary Shares"),
'#states' => array(
  'visible' => array(
    ':input[name="type_of_class"]' => array('value' => '1'),
  ),
),
);

$form['preferential']['share_type'] = array(
'#type' => 'item',
'#description' => t("You chose Preferential Shares"),
'#states' => array(
  'visible' => array(
    ':input[name="type_of_class"]' => array('value' => '2'),
  ),
),
);
return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about this being the best way but it's certainly *a* way to refactor your code:

```
function _services_wizard_share_capital_classes_add_el(&$form, $name, $description, $index) {
  $form[$name]['share_type'] = array(
    '#type' => 'item',
    '#description' => t($description),
    '#states' => array(
      'visible' => array(
        ':input[name="type_of_class"]' => array('value' => "$index"),
      ),
    )
  );
}

function services_wizard_share_capital_classes($form, &$form_state) {
  // Other code

  _services_wizard_share_capital_classes_add_el($form, 'ordinary', 'You chose Ordinary Shares', 1);
  _services_wizard_share_capital_classes_add_el($form, 'preferential', 'You chose Preferential Shares', 2);
  // etc...
}
```